# How can I see query warnings in error log in MariaDB

Tags: mariadb, relational-database

I'm trying to find out if I have any queries in my application that produce warnings in the DB.

I tried to `SET GLOBAL log_warnings=9;` as root and then execute a query that produces a warning (1364) *Field 'comment' doesn't have a default value* from my console. The query does produce the warning as to be seen in `SHOW WARNINGS` but it doesn't appear in

```
/var/log/mysql/error.log
```

where my `log_error` system variable points to. In fact, the file is present, but completely empty. It is owned by the *mysql* user (Debian) and was created this morning.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check on you /etc/log/mysql/my.cnf if `log_error` exist ? if NO you should add it.
Refer to : [https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/error-log/]

Comment: @SeddikOmar: thanks, yes, it exists, I can see it in the variables set to the path above, and the file gets created, but not logged to.

Comment: Does a query error log? (instead of a warning)

Comment: @PaulT. Nope, nothing the log is empty. I'm wondering if I have to set this setting explicitly in the conf, because it seems it's not, it's just at its default. But what a default value would that be if it contains a path, creates the file but doesn't log to it if it's just the default and not set explicitly. Unfortunately I have to stop the prod service to make a change in the config, which I don't want to do.